# Asp.Net Core Identity Create User

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have trouble creating a user. The process runs correctly, reads data to user, redirects to Home / Index, but there is no new user in the database.
I have the same code in DbSeeder and the users are created correctly there.

```cs
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(WorkerVM model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = new User()
                    {
                        FirstName = model.FirstName,
                        LastName = model.LastName,
                        Email = model.Username,
                        UserName = model.Username
                    };

                    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Worker");
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Registration Failed");

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: ReturnRedirectToAction is meant to be inside the if (result.Succeeded) statement. Outside the if statement, you return view to stay on the page if user creation wasn't successful. Place a debugger on your action method to see where the issue is

Comment: You creation code seems to be right, as @Qudus mentioned redirect should be done inside result succedeed, otherwise you should return `Page()`

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason that the user is not created in db is the new password doesn't fit the password criteria.

Check the password criterias and fix the password. Also fixed your code by moving "}" behind  the first return operator:

```
 var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
   if (result.Succeeded)
    {
     await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Worker");
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

you can manage your password criteria adding this code to startup

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(x => {
x.Password.RequireDigit = false;
x.Password.RequiredLength = 2;
x.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
x.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
x.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
x.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
x.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
x.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
x.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
});
```